# Can we elimanate NA in ggplot that is occuring. I tried with na.rm but its not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe df, But there are NA in a value column

```
p12
     Var1 ColA ColB
1       A   NA 44.7
2   asgfg  2.1   NA
3       B   NA 55.3
4     dds  2.1   NA
5     dfg  4.3   NA
6     dfh  2.1   NA
7     dgh  2.1   NA
8   dghgd  2.1   NA
9  dgrert  2.1   NA
```

SO i plot

```
ggplot(data=p12,aes(x=Var1,y=ColB,fill=Var1))+geom_bar(stat = "identity")+coord_flip()
```

It is even taking NA into account . Is there a way to eliminate this

Comment: Though likely too specific, `ggplot(data=p12[complete.cases(p12[,3]),],...)` will plot just the two rows with values in `ColB`. Otherwise, it's typically important to keep the `Var1` labels and show no data (in my opinion, though exceptions to this rule certainly exist).

Comment: Use the `filter` function from dplyr: `p12 %>% filter(!is.na(ColB)) %>% ggplot(aes(x=Var1,y=ColB,fill=Var1)) + …`